# access mapped network drive through impersonation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is it impossible to access the mapped network drive( mapped in user session) from service after impersonating the current user by using `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` Windows API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is impossible. Drive mappings are only established during an interactive logon. The `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` function does not impersonate the user's *entire logon session*, just their security context. This is only [one of the many things](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110928-00/?p=9533) that cannot be done using impersonation.

I suppose you *might* be able to do this by duplicating the user's login token (obtained from one of their interactive processes), and then using that to call the `CreateProcessAsUser` function. You would then launch a process that would work with the mapped network drive(s). I'm not absolutely certain that this will work, as I've never done it, but it seems theoretically possible.

Of course, it begs the question of why you need to follow such a circuitous route. It would be eminently more sensible to just run your code in the user's interactive process to begin with, as a standard Windows application.

This is not something that a service is designed to do. Services do not support mapped network drives. If you want to access a network resource from within a service, you should just use the UNC path.

Comment: A few more words on what else can go wrong when impersonating: [Does this operation work when impersonating? The default answer is NO](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110928-00/?p=9533).

Comment: Thanks! I had somehow either missed that blog post, or completely forgotten about it. I should have expected Raymond had written about this! Incorporated the link into my answer for greater visibility.

Comment: Another authoritative [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143.aspx) on services and why you can't use redirected drives. ("[R]edirected drives cannot be shared between processes running under different user accounts.")

Comment: UNC paths *might* work, if the user is logged into a domain account and the server is in the same domain as the client.  I'm not sure.

Comment: What if the service is running as System, and the UNC path is only accessible with the user's domain credentials? Apart from cleartext credentials, is there anything the user's program can send to the service that would enable the service to access the UNC path?